# Why is Perl regex \K not excluding the pattern matched before \K?

Tags: regex, perl

I have a file called test.txt with the following:

```
> Last login: Mon Jul 13 05:09:33 2020 You have mail.   
> ******************************
> cat, you have just logged into machine sampleserver2    
> ******************************
> 
> --------------------------------------------------------------  
> | To switch environments later, run:                         |
> |                                                            |
> | change                                                     |
> |                                                            |
> --------------------------------------------------------------
> 
> 
> Current Dir => /apps/users/cat     Oracle SID: SAMPLE
> cat@sampleserver2:
```

I try running the command below to only return the last colon but it returns the full line. To my understanding it should only be returning the *:* and not *cat@sampleserver2:*. What am I doing wrong? I'm also using a version of Perl that should be able to handle this.

```
cat test.txt | perl -ne 'print if /.+@.+\K:/'
cat@sampleserver2:
```

```
% perl -v 
This is perl 5, version 30, subversion 1 (v5.30.1) built for
x86_64-linux-ld
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want to say:

```
perl -ne 'print $& if /.+@.+\K:/' test.txt
```

which outputs:

```
:
```

- The statement `print if CONDITION` is equivalent to `print $_ if CONDITION` and just prints the line *without* modifications if the CONDITION meets.
  Please use `$&` instead.
- The second argument `cat@sampleserver2:` will cause an error saying
  "Can't open cat@sampleserver2:: No such file or directory."

Comment: Some suggestions that also may help:
1. You can always see more verbose what is really going on this way: `perl -MO=Deparse,-p -ne 'print if /.+@.+\K:/'`
2. Useful documentation:
`perldoc perlvar` - description of all special variables or `perldoc -v '$_'` for single variable
`perldoc -f print`
`perldoc perlre` - perl regular expressions documentation
`perldoc perlrun` - mustread dock for one-liner authors

Comment: Thank you both this was really helpful. The second argument was a copy and paste error on my end. This was actually the output cat test.txt | perl -ne 'print if /.+@.+\K:/'

Answer (score 1):

The `\K` [ignores part of the match](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2012/10/ignore-part-of-a-substitutions-match/) so it doesn't show up in `$&` (or the part of the string that `s///` will replace. But, you output `$_`, the default variable that `print` uses when you give it no argument.

I don't know why you want to return the last colon. If you know that you are only going to output the colon, you don't need fancy regex features. Match the line then output the known string:

```
 print ':' if /.+\@.+:/
```

But I suspect you are actually trying to do something else. Are you trying to skip the login banner and capture whatever is after the first command-line prompt?

---

Also, you one-liner looks suspicious. You have:

```
cat test.txt | perl -ne 'print if /.+@.+\K:/' cat@sampleserver2:
```

That `cat@sampleserver2:` is a command-line argument and the implicit `while(<>){...}` from the `-n` switch will try to open a file with that name and read it. Maybe you have a file named that. That filename isn't the target for the match operator, but I suspect you think it is.

But, if you have a file with that name, why are you also piping another file? You don't need the `cat` there. This will read through lines of *test.txt*:

```
% perl -ne 'print if /.+@.+\K:/' test.txt
```