# How can I get match using \K in Perl Expect.pm

Tags: regex, perl

I have the following code but instead of returning only the colon(:) it returns the whole string. It looks like Expect.pm is ignoring \K.

```
my @match = $exp->expect(
    60,
    [ qr/.+@.+\K:/ => sub { $type = 'commandprompt' } ],
    [ timeout => sub { die "Timeout reached.  Unable to determine output." } ],
);
```

My input for this is a line ending in **cat@sampleserver2:**

My expected result is to just return colon(:) in the $match from Expect.pm. Instead it's returning the full string. I've also tried this qr/[:]\s?\r?$/ but it returns lines where a colon(:) is not at the end of the line such as ***ORACLE SID: abcdef*** which is not my expected results.

What can I do to get the $match to match colon(:) only?

Comment: PCRE or Perl same, if this regex `.+@.+\K:` matches, it _WILL_ have only a colon in the match and nothing else. So, it doesn't seem possible to contain the whole string `cat@sampleserver2:` if it uses the perl engine.

Comment: Didn't you ask a similar question yesterday https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62886586/why-is-perl-regex-k-not-excluding-the-pattern-matched-before-k

Comment: Is it possible the latest Perl has an option to ignore the `\K` construct ?

Comment: @Barmar yes. I got the answer to that and it helped me to determine that Perl is working as expected. I was able to return the colon only. I'm debugging some code that we moved to a new server and I'm trying to understand why it's not working. I tracked it down to the Expect.pm module and now realize that the regexs are not working as expected.

Comment: @Maxt8r, No . . .

Comment: Then it looks like Expect.pm module is front loading the return array with the original string, because up to `\K` is not included as part of the match. Don't see any capture groups so the regex is not returning that. I would go through the source code to see what its doing.

Comment: As I noted in your previous answer, `\K` doesn't do whatever you are think it is doing. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62886586/why-is-perl-regex-k-not-excluding-the-pattern-matched-before-k